# transform json input using jq command

Tags: jq

I have the following json input from a internet service:

```
{
  "sunarme": "foo",
  "id": "foo-id",
  "name": "Foo bar",
  "profile": [
    {
      "id": "test1",
      "products": [
        "product1",
        "product2"
      ],
      "description": "test1 description"
     },
     {
      "id": "test2",
      "products": [
        "product3",
        "product4",
        "product5"
      ],
      "description": "test2 description"
     },
     {
      "id": "test3",
      "products": [
        "product6",
        "product7",
        "product8"
      ],
      "description": "test2 description"
      }
   ]
}
```

So I need to transform profile key from array to json object. This is the desired output:

```
{
  "sunarme": "foo",
  "id": "foo-id",
  "name": "Foo bar",
  "profile": {
      "test1": [
        "product1",
        "product2"
      ],
      "test2": [
        "product3",
        "product4",
        "product5"
      ],
      "test3": [
        "product6",
        "product7",
        "product8"
      ]
   }
}
```

I don't have any idea how to do it in jq command, please, could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `with_entries` which lets you convert the array into an object if you adjust the `.key`s accordingly.

```sh
jq '.profile |= with_entries(.key = .value.id | .value |= .products)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/J4L-Tx8hB9)

Or use `reduce` to build the object by iterating through the array.

```sh
jq '.profile |= reduce .[] as $p ({}; .[$p.id] = $p.products)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/OBNQKcbabS)

Or use `map` to convert each array item into an object, then merge them using `add`.

```sh
jq '.profile |= (map({(.id): .products}) | add)'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/skKpF1d_RW)

Output is:

```json
{
  "sunarme": "foo",
  "id": "foo-id",
  "name": "Foo bar",
  "profile": {
    "test1": [
      "product1",
      "product2"
    ],
    "test2": [
      "product3",
      "product4",
      "product5"
    ],
    "test3": [
      "product6",
      "product7",
      "product8"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm